# Silex 2: Declare {_locale} optional in routings

Tags: php, controller, routes, locale, silex

I would like routing these kind of URLs:

```
/hello/{name}
/en/hello/{name}
/es/hello/{name}
```

I have created this Controller class:

```
<?php

namespace Fw\Controllers;

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Fw\Application as FwApplication;

class Hello implements ControllerProviderInterface {

    const URL_BASE = '/hello';
    const URL_BASE_LOCALE = '/{_locale}/hello';

    public function connect(Application $app) {
        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];

        $controllers
                ->get('/{name}/', array($this, 'nameAction'))
                ->bind('hello_name')
        ;

        return $controllers;
    }

    public function nameAction(FwApplication\ApplicationBase $app, Request $request, $name) {
        return new Response('Hello ' . $name, 200);
    }
}
```

And it has been registered in this way:

```
$app->mount(FwControllers\Hello::URL_BASE_LOCALE, new FwControllers\Hello());
$app->mount(FwControllers\Hello::URL_BASE, new FwControllers\Hello());
```

This URL works good: /hello/foo
But this one not: /en/hello/foo, this error is shown:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouterListener.php line 125: No route found
>   for "GET /en/hello/foo/"

It seems that the second "mount" sentence is overwritten to first one.

Can anybody help me with this problem? How can I set routing with optional {_locale}?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem and wrote service provider that automatically adds locale to all routes https://github.com/pmaxs/silex-locale. May be it will satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer :) Your library works well and it almost complains my requirements. One thing: If my available languages are "es", "en", is it possible if the loaded URL is "/fr/hello/foo" instead to thrown NotFoundHttpException, redirect (301) to default "/en/hello/foo" or "/hello/foo"?

Comment: You can add `fr` as possible locale and redirect in middlware `$app->before(function(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request) {
    if ($request->getLocale() == 'fr') redirect ...;
});`

Comment: Thanks for you help!

Comment: If I do this return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('homepage', ["locale" => 'es']), 301); I get this error Parameter "locale" for route "homepage" must match "((?:en|es)/)?" ("es" given) to generate a corresponding URL. How can I set the locale now?

Comment: `["locale" => 'es/']` or `$app['locale.url_generator']->getIndexUrlForLocale('es')`

Comment: Hi, I have updated my silex version from v.2.0.2 to v.2.0.4, and your service provider from 2.0.4 to 2.0.9 and an error is produced:  `ContextErrorException in LocaleServiceProvider.php line 65: Notice: Undefined property: Pmaxs\Silex\Locale\Provider\LocaleServiceProvider::$resolve_by_host`

Comment: I've fixed this error. About errors better write on github https://github.com/pmaxs/silex-locale/issues